# Happy birthday journey issue

Tags: journeybuilder

I'm setting up a happy birthday journey in the journey builder.

We want to send the email at the start of the customers birthday month (i.e the customers birthday is on the 10th of December and the birthday month is December).

Can we do this? And will it be an issue it the data column type is "text" not "date'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the contains a function to check if the text field contains particular month like ' Birthdate Contains December' to include record and set the date to be sent as first of that particular month.